# use cx_Oracle to handle .sql script

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
# -*-coding: UTF-8 -*-
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('test/test01@10.10.2.3/test') 
cursor =conn.cursor()
f = open('test001.txt','r',encoding='gbk')
full_sql = f.read()
sql_commands = full_sql.split(';')

for sql_command in sql_commands:
    cursor.execute(sql_command)}
```

systems error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 353-357: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: seems like you can't actually read the file, but it's hard to say what's wrong here unless you provide more information like full stacktrace.
can you add few lines from test001.txt ?

Comment: delete from test  where TERM_ID = '2017-04' and TERM_VERSION_ID = '2017-04-01

    insert into test (ID, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8)
values ('test', null, '2017-04-01-2017-04-30', '2017-04-01-2017-04-30_V_4', '1', '2', '3', 4)
    insert into test (ID, ID2, ID3, ID4, ID5, ID6, ID7, ID8)
values ('test', null, '2017-04-01-2017-04-30', '2017-04-01-2017-04-30_V_4', '7', '8', '9', 10)

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle did you install?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with cx_Oracle 6.0rc1 where mixed text encodings on an Windows OS error caused the import of cx_Oracle to display various `UnicodeEncodeError` messages.  Posts like [this](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/40) have the issue.  The cx_Oracle bug has been [fixed on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/commit/2e9c412d41aa4d303ce088852c65a2d0b9dfd7f1) but a release to PyPi has not yet been made (it'll come soon). If you can install cx_Oracle from GitHub you will see the actual OS error - which you then will have to fix.

The actual root of the problem causing the OS to generate an error may be that you don't have Oracle client libraries in your path, that the libraries are not the same architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) as Python, or that you don't have the correct VS Redistributable for your version of the Oracle client libraries.  The required VS Redistributables are listed on the Instant Client download pages ([32-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html) and [64-bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)).